# How can I stop github actions from requiring old nodejs builds?

Tags: node.js, github, upgrade, github-actions

I've got a project that just upgraded from nodejs 10, to nodejs 14. We use github actions for CI, so the node.js.yml changed from

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]
```

to

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
```

Building with node 14 is working fine, but github is preventing a PR from going through because "Not all checks have completed yet", saying "build (10.x) Expected — Waiting for status to be reported".

Of course, I don't want to keep checking against version 10 forever, so I don't want to put it back into the yml. How can I get github to drop 10?

Comment: The change has to be merged to the default branch (typically 'master' or 'main'). Is it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably set this as a required build in the branch protection settings for your repository.  However, you no longer have this build, so GitHub's waiting for it to complete (which it never will).  If you go into Settings → Branches → Branch Protection Rules, you can disable the old required status checks and enable the new ones.